# Does this a function $x+y \rightarrow x^2+y^2$ exist?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

I don't know if this exists, but it would make my algebra easier if it did instead of having to use complicated radicals to solve an equation.

If $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $h(x,y)=x+y$, is there a real or complex function $f$ such that $f(x+y)=x^{2}+y^{2}$? And if so, what is it?

Comment: If there were, what would $f(4)$ be? Would it be $f(2+2) = 2^2+2^2 = 8$, or $f(3+1) = 3^2+1^2 = 10$?

Comment: Well I don't know how valid testing only real values is because there's all kinds of special functions with weird properties. How do I know there isn't some weird function like the exponential integral plus the gamma function or something like that which has some branch that turn x+y into x^2+y^2? The "variables" I want to manipulate are real, but the function itself can still any combination use imaginary numbers or functions of complex numbers in some way. I mean there's already a weird complicated functional relationship that shows Riemannchi(x)=Riemannchi(1-x).

Comment: $f$ is a function, so if you feed it a number, it produces one (and only one) number. So if you feed it the number 4, you have to tell me what it produces. But 4 can be written in multiple ways as a sum of two numbers, and thus the value of the function depends on the representation you choose for 4. The function is not well-defined.

Comment: Okay, but I mean is there any function at all that has this property that uses complex numbers? Sin and cosine take real numbers as an input and give real numbers as an output, but they still have an unintuitive imaginary form.

Comment: @user608672 If you show the function is inconsistent, even when restricted to real numbers as input, then it will still be inconsistent if you try to extend it to complex numbers.

Comment: The point here is that "testing only real numbers" is sufficient because you want it to work for real numbers, and so the fact is that it does not (as @rogerl showed you).

Comment: "and $h(x,y)=x+y$" - where do you use this? Also, choosing $y=0$ you must have $f(x)=x^2$, but clearly $f(x+y)=(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2=x^2+y^2$ only if $2xy=0$...

Comment: f(x+y) should be equal to (x^2+y^2), not (x^y)^2. If it was (x^y)^2 this question wouldn't never come up. You would need to show how 2xy is equal to a function of f(x+y) in the first place in order to use it for defining a function that will return x^2+y^2 as a function of x+y. If you subtract 2xy, then you're just saying h(x,y)-2xy = x^2+y^2 which doesn't solve anything, it says nothing about what maps x+y to x^2+y^2.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. $f(x+y)=(x+y)^2$ follows from the fact that $f(x)=x^2$, which in turn follows from your condition by putting $y=0$ (not sure why you wrote (x^y)^2). By the way if you enclose expressions in dollars it looks much better, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for more. Also I will ask again, what is the $h(x,y)$? Why do you define it if you don't use it? You could as well define $q(x,y)=x+5y$...

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't exist because $f(0)=f(-1 + 1) = 2$ and $f(0)=f(2+-2)=8$.

Comment: Couldn't that simply suggest that this function has multiple branches? Arcsin has multiple output values, and when you feed it a real number, it still outputs a real number over a specific domain. It's comprised of imaginary variables even though its form is unintuitive. So what I would expect is that there is some kind of unusual looking complex/imaginary function where you would have to be selective of the branch you're using to satisfy the x+y formula.

Comment: @user608672: if an input has multiple outputs, then it is not a function. Please look up the definition of function.

Comment: That's still just a cop-out to get out defending your claim. Arcsin has multiple outputs, but we can still adjust it as needed to be a function when we're ready to use it over a specific range, pretending arcsin doesn't exist doesn't solve anything.

Comment: @user608672: The two cases are different. If you restrict the range of $f$, then certain $(x,y)$ pairs wouldn't even be allowed in your equation. In fact, you might prove to yourself that John Douma's example can be generalized to show that $f(0)=r$ for any $r\geq 0$, which means restricting the range is not really going to help, since it could never contain more than one positive real number.

Comment: arcsin does *not* have multiple outputs.  1) we restrict outputs to only values between -90 and 90 degrees 2) for the few multivalue "functions" that *seem* to allow multiple outputs.  Example $\ln w = x + 2k \pi i$ that output is not actually the infinite values of $x + 2k \pi i$ but the *single* equivalence class of $\{x + 2k \pi i\}$.  The sets $[w] = \{a^2 + b^2| a+b = w\}$  is not an equivalence class.  the $[w]$ are not distinct.

Comment: "That's still just a cop-out to get out defending your claim."  That is exceedingly rude!  And, as it turns out, fairly ignorant.

Answer (score 4):

It cant be a single value function because if $w = a+ b = c+d$ then $f(w) = a^2 + b^2$ which may not equal $c^2 + d^2$ so it is not well defined.

But in you comments you seem to ask about multivalued "functions" with branches such as $\arcsin$ and $\sqrt{}$ and $\ln$ of complex numbers where if $f(x) = y$ it can actually be argued that there are a set of $\{y_\alpha\}$ where the each of the $y_\alpha$ can be argued is legitimate value for $f(x)$.

This "branching", of course, violates the definition of a function.  And for the must part this functions are restricted to only specific outcomes.  For example: although $\sin \theta = \sin (\pi - \theta) = \sin (\theta + 2\pi)=x$ it would seem $\arcsin x$ could be all of $\theta, \pi - \theta,$ or $\theta + 2\pi$.  But this is *not* what happens because we restrict, by definition, that $\arcsin x$ must be a value between $-\frac \pi 2$ (exclusive) and $\frac \pi 2$ (inclusive).

Likewis $\sqrt{x}$ is defined to always be non-negative.

This gets iffy with complex numbers that if $e^x = w$ then $e^{x + 2\pi i} = w$ and we don't bother to restrict $\ln w$ to a specific one of the infinite possible $x + 2\pi i$ but instead often say $\ln w = $ all and any of the $x + 2\pi i$ values.

This utterly bollocks the idea of "function" where $f(w)$ really has to be one thing.

Well, the work around is that $\ln$ is not a function of $\ln: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ but a function of $\ln:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C/mod 2\pi i$.  That is that $\ln$ doesn't map to a complex *number* but to an equivalence class.

We can say for two different complex $w_i \ne w_j$ that $w_i$ is *equivalent* to $w_j$ if $w_i - w_j = 2k \pi i$.  This relationship is an equivalence relations ship (its reflexive, symmetric and transitive; two elements related in this way might as well be considered for our purposes to be the same).  And for a given $w$ then the set of all $\{w_i| w_i - w = 2k\pi i$ for some integer $k\}$ is call an *equivalence class*.

So $\ln w = w + 2k\pi$ is not a single number, but a single *equivalence class*.

And $\mathbb C = \cup $ all equivalence classes.  And any two equivalence classes are distinct.

So  If we want to define $f(w) = a^2 + b^2$ when $w = a+b$ in this way as a multivalued "function" we must consider $a^2 + b^2$ as an equivalence class.

And if we do that, if we *want* say $w $ is equivalent to $v$ if there is a number $k$ so that $w = (k -e)^2 + e^2$ for some value $a$ and $v = (k-h)^2 + h^2$ for some $h$

But that is not an equivalence relation.  And the classes form by this are not distinct.

So this can't make any sense.